# How to make FullCalendar to display only future dates

Tags: fullcalendar

is there a way to show only dates from today. Not need to display past events and days.

If today is monday 15 March 2012, calendar start from today and display days to 15 April 2012.

Or from current week one month next.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved by iterating through fullcalendar events with classname **fc-future**. Here, is an example, where I'm adding a button for each future date.

```
 eventAfterAllRender: function (event) {
            if(event.name == 'month')
            {
                $('.fc-day.fc-future').each(function(){
                    $(this).css('position','relative');
                    $(this).append('<button type="button" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#XYZRequest">\n' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o requestSlot fc-day-number" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                        '</button>');
                });
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewRender to disable or enable prev/next button for future or past dates, by setting start date to control start date(I set current date as start date).

here is the code

```
viewRender: function (view, element)
    {
        var minDate = new Date();
        if (view.start <= minDate) {
            $('.fc-button-prev').addClass("fc-state-disabled");
        }
        else {
            $('.fc-button-prev').removeClass("fc-state-disabled");
        }
    }
```

vice versa for end date

Answer (score -1):

Use the ViewDisplay option

```
  viewDisplay   : function(view) {
      date = new Date() //is today's date.

      if((date - view.start) > 0) { jQuery('.fc-button-prev').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
      else { jQuery('.fc-button-prev').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }

      if((view.end - date) > 7809463201) { jQuery('.fc-button-next').addClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
      else { jQuery('.fc-button-next').removeClass("fc-state-disabled"); }
  },
```